# WP_Query multiple use of relation and/or

Tags: custom-field, wp-query

I have 2 custom fields that I would like to do a meta query on for a custom post type:

```
start_date
status
```

The outcome that I am looking for is

```
(start_date >= 1332115200 AND status = 1) OR (status = 2)
```

Is this possible to do with WP_Query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `meta_query` does not support these sorts of complex clauses in a sequence.

There are a couple of ways to work around this limitation.

- One is to filter `posts_where_paged` and modify the SQL manually. I just spent a couple minutes playing with this option, and it's not very straightforward - you'll have to write a pretty sophisticated `preg_replace()` to get the parentheses grouped right, etc.
- A more promising option is to get a whitelist of post ids manually, and then feed the results to the `post__in` parameter of `WP_Query`:

  ```
  global $wpdb;
  $post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
      SELECT post_id 
      FROM $wpdb->postmeta.pm 
      INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta.pm2 ON (pm.post_id = pm2.post_id)
      WHERE
          (pm.meta_key = 'status' AND pm.meta_value = '1' 
          AND pm2.meta_key = 'start_date' AND pm2.meta_value >= '1332115200')
      OR
          (pm.meta_key = 'status' AND pm.meta_value = '2')
  " ) );

  $query_args = array( 'post__in' => $post_ids ); // plus whatever else you want
  $my_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
  ```

  When `WP_Query` assembles the SQL, your `$post_ids` get turned into a clause like: `AND ID IN (1,2,3)`, which acts like a whitelist for whatever other parameters you pass to `WP_Query`.

Note that either way, this query is not going to be all that fast, since it requires some loose type casting on unindexed `meta_value`. Cache wisely :)

Comment: Thanks Boone.  I will implement the second solution.  Curious, how do you cache queries?

Comment: WP's Transients API is a nice way to do it, and it only takes a couple extra lines of code. http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/speed-up-your-wordpress-by-caching-custom-queries-using-transients-api/ is a decent introduction. The important part is to be sure that, in addition to setting a reasonable expiry date, you are sure to bust the cache (delete_transient()) when a new post is published with a 'start_date' or 'status' that needs to be counted in your query.

Comment: That's exactly what I had in mind.  Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is on [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) page, read the section, **Order & Order By Paramaters**.

In simple terms, ordering by meta_value means your query will have something like this in it

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'meta_key' => 'your_meta_key'
```

... but to do something like the example you gave is a bit more tricky though I think you'll find it's actually explained under the heading "Multiple Custom Field Handling:". Read that in conjunction with the second part of "Custom Field Parameters" and you should eventually get it.

Pay attention to the arrays. I think you should end up with 3 nested arrays in your case.