# How to query custom post types with mixed AND & OR statements for custom fields

Tags: wp-query, wpdb

I have a custom post type "`events`" which includes the custom fields "`is_premium`" (which is a true/false) and "`premium_expiry_date`" which is a date picker.

On my front end, I want to have "`events`" which are premium and their `premium_expiry_date` has not passed to be displayed on the top of the results.

I have managed to do half of that by `WP_Query` querying "`events`" for which the `is_premium==true && premium_expiry_date>$today` (my code shown below). I pull them successfully in a table which appears ton top of my page.

My problem is with displaying the rest, and avoiding double posts.

Essentially, I would need a query like `[ is_premium==false OR (is_premium==true AND premium_expiry_date<$today ) ]` but I know that `AND` and `OR` cannot be mixed in `WP_Query`.

I have tried to go into using `$wpdb` but with no luck (I am lacking SQL knowledge...)

My question is, could somebody either help me with how to syntax this using `$wpdb`, or direct me to a different path for achieving my desired result?

```
        // This is the code I use to show the premium events which have not occurred yet,
        // and their premium date has not passed
        $today = date('Ymd');
        $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'orderby'   => 'event_date',
        'meta_key'  => 'event_date',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'relation' => 'AND',
        'meta_query' => array(

                array(
                'key'       => $the_key, //I read this from a _GET value. It resembles another custom field
                'compare'   => 'LIKE',
                'value'     => $current_region->name, //filter based on current region
                ),

                array(
                'key'       => 'event_date',
                'compare'   => '>=',
                'value'     => $today
                ),

                array(
                'key'       => 'is_premium',
                'compare'   => '==',
                'value'     => 1
                ),

                array(
                'key'       => 'premium_expiry_date',
                'compare'   => '>=',
                'value'     => $today
                    ),

                ),  
            );

    ?>

    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

    <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>

    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

... END
```

Thanks a lot in advance

edit:

This is the output of  `<?php var_dump($GLOBALS['wpdb']->last_query) ?>` when placed right after `<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>`

```
string(97) "SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (147) ORDER BY meta_id ASC"
```

Comment: Could you file an [edit] and show us a `var_dump()` of `$GLOBALS['wpdb']->last_query` right after your `WP_Query`?

Comment: Take a look at this [WP_Query multiple use of relation and/or](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46139/wp-query-multiple-use-of-relation-and-or)

Comment: @kaiser added the output, is this what you asked?

Comment: @andreas yes this it :) Sidenote: Are you sure that the code in after "after" at "when placed right after" is the right one?

Comment: took me a while to understand what you just said haha... but yeah that was a typo - edit / fixed. I still don't understand much of the output though...

Comment: @Chittaranjan, thanks - indeed this looks very similar to what I want to do... however I do not really understand the arguments for '$wpdb' could you please help me with the syntax or go line by line? thanks a lot :)

Comment: You can have a look at the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)